# node-red dashboard auto size not working

Tags: css, node-red

I have a node-red installation with version 2.1.0 and I use a template node to display a table and everything works fine.

When I upgraded my node-red dashboard to 2.3.3. Then all my tables disappeared. I was not able to see the content at all. After some troubleshooting. I found out that if I change the size from auto size to a fix size then I can show the content in the tables.

And does anyone know if this is a bug or by design. And why should not auto size work?

By the way in my template I add a complete html page with html tags and header and body. And reference bootstrap styles and other. Maybe this can cause a problem in the new version?

What is best practise in template nodes. Use complete html tags or just the subset and add css references in some config?

Comment: This sort of things will be better discussed on the Node-RED Slack instance in the #dashboard-ui room. You can find the link to the Slack instance on the Node-RED home page

Comment: Ok, I try there instead.